# How do I read a video uploaded to a Flask app with cv2.VideoCapture()?

Tags: python, html, flask, opencv

Is it possible to create a web app to send video from our computer and process it through `cv2.VideoCapture()`?

In index.html, I got the video input through

```
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In main.py

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logging.debug('Before my_prediction')
        uploaded_file = request.files['filename']
        extent = uploaded_file.filename.split('.')[1]
        app.logger.info(extent)
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(uploaded_file)
```

I tried doing that but got this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type FileStorage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the file to a temporary file on your server using [`FileStorage.save()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save) and then pass the name of that temporary file to `cv2.VideoCapture`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tempfile

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.files['filename']
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
            temp_filename = Path(td) / 'uploaded_video'
            uploaded_file.save(temp_filename)

            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(temp_filename))
            # do stuff with vidcap
```

[`Request.files`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#flask.Request.files) is a dictionary (more precisely a [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict)) of [`FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) objects, whereas `cv2.VideoCapture` expects a string that is a path to a file.